# Linux LXD container not getting IP from DHCP Ubuntu 16.04 TLS

Tags: networking, lxc, ubuntu-server, lxd

This is my first time when I am setting up LXD to run multiple containers. I have done all the configuration steps but my container not getting IP address from DHCP server which is running inside my organization. Please help me out.

I am using Bridge interface profile. Below are changes I have made:

```
root@DMG-LXD-TVM2:~# vi /etc/network/interfaces

auto  br0
iface br0   inet dhcp
    bridge-ports ens32
    bridge-ifaces ens32
iface ens32 inet dhcp


root@DMG-LXD-TVM2:~# lxc list
| NAME        |  STATE  |       IPV4       | IPV6 |    TYPE    | SNAPSHOTS |
| Continer1   | RUNNING |                  |      | PERSISTENT | 0         |
```

[IP and interface details what i setup on my ubuntu machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4XGW.png)

[Dhcp message when doing ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0 inside container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3V5iJ.png)

Comment: You should write your question in a way that inspires people who are paid nothing to help you

Comment: Now it's seems okay, please help me out

Answer (score 3):

This is an older question, but I decided to answer it, since I got stuck on the same topic and the solution isn't exactly obvious.

If you want your container to obtain its ip configuration from an external device (e.g. internet router, company dhcp server), you need to tell it so, at creation time. This is done via a configuration parameter pair `user.network_mode=dhcp`
Since this configuration is in "user" space, it is not normed, but works on ubuntu 16.04. For details see: https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/doc/configuration.md

Step 1: create bridge on the host in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
 auto br0
 iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports ens32
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
```

Step 2: create you own lxd profile called mydhcp

```
lxd profile create mydhcp
```

or reconfigure your default lxd configuration by calling

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -p medium lxd
```

(You need to choose  at the first prompt and add  on the second prompt, then enter your bridge's name)

If you use your own profile, edit it

```
lxc profile edit mydhcp
```

paste the following

```
name: mydhcp
config:
  user.network_mode: dhcp
description: Profile for creating dhcp containers
devices:
  eth0:
    name: eth0
    nictype: bridged
    parent: br0
    type: nic
```

(Note the spaces - this is a YAML file, the spaces matter!)

Step 3: create a new container using you mydhcp profile

```
lxc launch ubuntu:16.04 mydhcpcontainer -p mydhcp -c user.network_mode=dhcp
```

if you changed the default lxd configuration in the previous step, just enter

```
lxc launch ubuntu:16.04 mydhcpcontainer -c user.network_mode=dhcp
```

Check your new container's ip address with

```
lxc exec mydhcpcontainer -- ifconfig
```